# Removing pixel artifact links when trying to make Icon Image links

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make icons that change color when hovered over, and link to a new tab clicked. The code I have does that just fine, but there are these weird '-' pixels that are elsewhere on the page (not where I want) and also change the color of the icon and go to a new tab when clicked. **How do I remove these left over dash pixel links? Or, is there a different/better way to make these icon image links?**

Here is HTML of the issue:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="stackO.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class = "webParent">
    <a href = "https://github.com" id = "icon1" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      <img class = "imageWEB"
      src = "ImagesWebsite\github2.png" alt = "github" width = "70" height = "70"/>
      <img class = "imageWEB2" 
      src = "ImagesWebsite\github1.png" alt = "github2" width = "70" height = "70"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class = "webParent2">
    <a href = "https://youtube.com" id = "icon2" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      <img class = "imageWEB3"
      src = "ImagesWebsite\play1.png" alt = "play2" width = "70" height = "70"/>
      <img class = "imageWEB4" 
      src = "ImagesWebsite\play2.png" alt = "play1" width = "70" height = "70"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is CSS of the issue:

```
  .webParent2 {
    display:contents;
  }
  .webParent2:hover .imageWEB4{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .imageWEB3 {
    position: relative; 
    top: 200px;
    left: 74px;
  }
  .imageWEB4 {
    position:relative; 
    top: 200px;
  }
  .webParent {
    display:contents;
  }
  .webParent:hover .imageWEB2{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .imageWEB {
    position:relative; 
    top: 200px;
    left: 74px;
  }
  .imageWEB2 {
    position:relative; 
    top: 200px;
  }
```

Below is a GIF of the aforementioned problem. I want to remove those links at the top.
[image: GIF of aforementioned problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the underline is because of the default underline of the a tag you have. You can remove it by puttin text-decoration:none on your links so the line will disappear. Like below. Let me know

```css
.webParent2, .wenParent {
    display:contents;
  }
  .webParent2:hover .imageWEB4{
    visibility: hidden;
  
  }
 

  

  .webParent:hover .imageWEB2{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  .imageWEB {
     position:absolute;  
    top: 200px;
    left: 74px;
  }
  
  .imageWEB2 {
    position:absolute; 
    top: 200px;
    left: 74px;
  }
  
  
.imageWEB3 {
     position:absolute; 
    top: 200px;
    left: 148px;
   
  }
  .imageWEB4 {
     position:absolute; 
    top: 200px;
    left: 148px;
  }


a:-webkit-any-link {text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="stackO.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class = "webParent">
    <a href = "https://github.com" id = "icon1" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      <img class = "imageWEB"
      src = "https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/351-3511429_sample-inspection-report-lake-ozark-mo-inspection-doctor-sample-icon-png.png" alt = "github" width = "70" height = "70"/>
      </a>
      
      <a href = "https://github.com" id = "icon1" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      <img class = "imageWEB2" 
      src = "https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/8/Sample.png" alt = "github2" width = "70" height = "70"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class = "webParent2">
    <a href = "https://youtube.com" id = "icon2" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      <img class = "imageWEB3"
      src = "https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/351-3511429_sample-inspection-report-lake-ozark-mo-inspection-doctor-sample-icon-png.png" alt = "play2" width = "70" height = "70"/>
      </a>
      
      <a href = "https://youtube.com" id = "icon2" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      <img class = "imageWEB4" 
      src = "https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/8/Sample.png" alt = "play1" width = "70" height = "70"/>
    </a>
    
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This successfully removes the underline but the link still remains at the top when hovered, it's just not visible. Any idea how to disable the top link but keep the link on the icon enabled? I keep ending up disabling both links when I try to disable those top invisible ones.

Comment: @BillBumbleton am i understanding it right. you have 4 images and you want to remove 1 on hover and show the other on hover is that right?

Comment: Yeah, I have both images in the same place, and on hover, one goes invisible and the other one is revealed and can be clicked. That part is working, it's just those links at the top I'm trying to remove. Thanks for the help

Comment: ok let me edit the answer for you..  and provide you a sample you can work with.

Comment: @BillBumbleton try positioning your icons absolute and adjusting left. see if that will work for you. look sample above, Let me know if that wont work for you then I'll make a sample icon you can work with.